# Printing in Base 10-16 with letters (I am stuck on a project where I have to print out any number)

Tags: c++

I am stuck on a project where I have to print out any number in any base from 10-16. The problem is that in those bases, you have to add a letter to the front, which I don't really understand how to do with recursion. If I do 246 in base 16, I get 156. I know that the actual answer should be F6. 15 translates to F when converting. But how would I do that and where do I add the code?

```
int conversionFunction(int num, int base)
{
     if (num == 0)
        return 0;
     int x = num % base;
     num /= base;
     if (x < 0)
        num = num + 1; 
     conversionFunction(num, base);
     if (x < 0){
        cout << x+(base * -1);
     }
     else{
        cout << x;
        return x;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the possibility of printing a **character** instead instead of printing the **number** x. [Look at the ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), notice that the numbers 0-9 have sequential numeric values and so do the letters A-Z.

You can exploit that property:

```
if (x < 10) cout << '0' + x; // prints a character!
else cout << 'A' + (x - 10); // prints a character!
```